# SQL Prefix issue N with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @XML_VC_8 XML;
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @PreFix NVACHAR(MAX);

SET @PreFix ='N' 
SET @XML_VC_8 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><test>fdff مرحبا</test>';
SET @string = @PreFix + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @XML_VC_8);

PRINT @string
```

Issue is the Arabic text is not printed - please can anyone resolve my issue?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: sql server 2014 yea sir is product specfic

Comment: why do you need to put 'N' in a variable?

Comment: I think is better that you tell us what do you want to do with the arabic text

Comment: Well, in your `SET @string` line, you **explicitly** convert it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` which is **NON-Unicode** and stuff will not preserve Arabic characters......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the `N variable` and changing encoding to `utf-16`, this should get your characters

```
Declare @XML_VC_8 XML;
Declare @string nvarchar(max);


set @XML_VC_8 = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><test>fdff مرحبا</test>';
set @string=Convert(nvarchar(max),@XML_VC_8);
print @string
```

Answer (score 2):

These work fine!

```
DECLARE @XML_VC_8 XML;
SET @XML_VC_8 = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><test>fdff مرحبا</test>';
SELECT @XML_VC_8
```

[image]